# Dynamically set JSON key in GSON

Tags: java, gson

I am writing an `Android` app that sends some data over JSON. I'm using `GSON` to Serialise/Deserialise my objects. I have this working with a few objects already, but one endpoint/object is giving me trouble.

The functionality of the app is basically multiple choice questions. The user can choose one of A, B, C or D for roughly 10 questions, and based on the selection, there's also a `long` value that is associated with this selection.

Here is an example of the JSON I am trying to POST:

```
{
    "user": "abcd1234",
    "pass": "abc123",
    "itemID": 1234,
    "listSelection": [
        ("A", 21),
        ("D", 18),
        ("B", 34),
        ...
    ]
}
```

So the trouble is with the `listSelection` object. I don't control the API. The owner sent me the above sample to use. I'd rather have it in the form of `answer: A, value: 21` but the owner wants tuples.

I am trying to create the class in Java to make GSON create the above to send over POST to the API, but my understanding of this process is that GSON names the key based on the variable name. This is fine for the `user`, `pass` and `itemID` but for the items within the `listSelection` where the key is dynamic, this does not work. I'm not sure if I need to put it in a map, or if there's another way in GSON for dynamically setting the key.

I was thinking something like this:

```
public class AnswerSet {

    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private int itemID;
    private List<Answer> listSelection;
}
```

where the `Answer` class might be:

```
public class Answer {

    private String answer;
    private long answerValue;
}
```

But this will format the `JSON` incorrectly.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Why the last thing you proposed would format incorrectly?

Comment: It will fomat in the form `"answer": "A", "answerValue": 21` instead of `"A" : 21`

Comment: I suppose you need implement custom serializer for Answer, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case

Comment: Those pairs must be referred to by same name. I think is not possible to have what you say. How could that be deserialized afterwards?

Comment: Are you sure that your answers are surrounded by `(` `)` and not `{` `}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid JSON (try running it through a [validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)), so I would not expect GSON to be able to parse it. You will have to implement your own parser or change the POST to valid JSON.

Comment: OK thanks, I managed to get the JSON changed to a valid format.