# Updating realm object by increments

Tags: android, realm

I have a realm object that contains list of items with IDs

```
@SerializedName("products")
RealmList<ProductDialItem> products;
@SerializedName("previous_suppliers")
RealmList<SuppliersDialItem> previousSuppliers;
@SerializedName("tariffs")
RealmList<TariffsDialItem> tariffs;
@SerializedName("deposit_frequencies")
RealmList<SimpleDialItem> depositFrequencies;
@SerializedName("bank_codes")
RealmList<SimpleDialItem> bankCodes;
@SerializedName("gas_usages")
RealmList<SimpleDialItem> gasUsages;
```

And so on, each item in list has ID. The server sends a json response with values to be filled in the object.

But we also use Last-Modified header, so that server only sends items that changed. I want only to update items, not to delete any of them.

Tl;dr how do I only update/add items to realm, but not delete them

Comment: try to create a custom JsonSerializer like the one in the example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case

Comment: The object contains around ~30 fields, wouldn't there be a more automated way ?

Comment: I will put another answer

Comment: You don't have to update the `RealmList`, just update the `ProductDialItem`/`SuppliersDialItem`/`SimpleDialItem` the corresponding items in the `RealmList` will be changed. Is that what you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

let the object contain:

```
class MyClass{

int x = 0;

int y = 0;

int z = 0;

}
```

then if you need to increment the variables from the web:

```
MyClass finalObject = new MyClass();

MyClass tempObject = new Gson().fromJson(response,MyClass.class);

incrementObjects(tempObject,finalObject);
```

and now create the method incrementObjects() :

```
private void incrementObjects(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2){
obj2.x += obj1.x;
obj2.y += obj1.y;
obj2.z += obj1.z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Query on Realm when you get updated data response like,

```
//Create RealmList when you get updated Data in your api response.
RealmList<YourModel> updatedData = yourResponseData.getData();

//Get data from localDatabase and Query on
RealmQuery<YourModel> where = mRealm.where(YourModel.class);

     for (int i = 0; i < updatedData.size(); i++) {

          //put condition to match data based on your database.
          where = where.notEqualTo(YourModel.NAME,updatedData.get(i).getName());
     }


//Now this where.findAll(); , will return list of data which is notEqual To updatedData 
//perform update operation with this or deleteFrom local Data and insert new/updated Data.

where.findAll();
```

Comment: But I will have to do this for each realmlist individually ? there are ~30 of them

Comment: Then without doing this how u will identify that which record/data is updated ?