# Own Firebase deserializer

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have old legacy code that I don't want to rewrite and I'm using gson and io.gsonfire to do mapping with special json to my java class. I want to just transform Datasnapshot to json string so I can use my other implementation. I will not be able to use Datasnapshot.getValue(SomeClass.class) because my transformer is special.

```
public class BlockTypeSelector {

public Gson createGson(){

    GsonFireBuilder builder = new GsonFireBuilder()
    .registerTypeSelector(AbstractPhrase.class, new TypeSelector<AbstractPhrase>() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends AbstractPhrase> getClassForElement( JsonElement readElement) {
             JsonElement element = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("dotted");
             if( element != null ){
                  return DottedFillPhrase.class;
             }

            return Phrase.class;
        }

    })
    .registerTypeSelector(AbstractParagraph.class, new TypeSelector<AbstractParagraph>() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends AbstractParagraph> getClassForElement( JsonElement readElement) {
             JsonElement element = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("cells");
             if( element != null ){
                  return TableParagraph.class;
             }

             element = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("padding");
             if( element != null ){
                return TableCell.class;
             }

             element = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("fill");
             if( element != null ){
                return FillParagraph.class;
             }

            return Paragraph.class;
        }

    })
    .registerTypeSelector(BaseElement.class, new TypeSelector<BaseElement>() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends BaseElement> getClassForElement(JsonElement readElement) {
            JsonElement element = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("type");
            if( element == null ){
                throw new JsonSyntaxException( "You must have a type in block" );
            }
            String kind = element.getAsString();
            if(kind.equals("LINE")){
                return Line.class;
            }else if(kind.equals("BLOCK")) {
                return Block.class; 
            }else if(kind.equals("IMAGE")) {
                return Image.class; 
            }else if(kind.equals("QR")) {
                return QRCode.class; 
            }else if(kind.equals("BARCODE")) {
                return Barcode.class; 
            } else {
                return null; //returning null will trigger Gson's default behavior
            }
        }
    });

    return builder.createGson();


}

}
```

So any pointers on how to make something like this

```
{ key = 787878, value = {document={pages={0={blocks={0={position={3=60.1, 2=50, 1=28.95, 0=25.6}, useAscender=true, type=BLOCK, border={thickness=0.1}}}}}, name=22323}} }
```

To json String? My worries is the 3:60 and that stuff. How can I know that it is an array and not "3" : "60" json?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are already using Gson to parse JSON.  You could also use Gson to [serialize JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case) as well by digging into the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) using its own API and using that to populate some JSON output.

If you do this, I suspect it would be about the same amount of effort as writing code to navigate a DataSnapshot and convert its *directly* your data model, and it will run a lot faster than converting it to JSON, then to your model.

Comment: The DataSnapshot gives me no power to serialize my object.

Comment: You have to use its API (that I linked to) to get the values inside it.  getChildren(), child(), and value() are all you need.