# Gson error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator declares multiple JSON fields named mHandler

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to convert a `List` of a custom object called `MyData`:

```
class MyData {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Drawable AppIcon;

    public MyData() {}

    public MyData(String id, String title, Drawable _AppIcon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.AppIcon = _AppIcon;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Drawable getAppIcon() {
        return this.AppIcon;
    }

}
```

I am trying to convert it as I read in the `Gson` documentation:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyData>>(){}.getType();
List<MyData> appsList = new ArrayList<>();
String ArrayStr = new Gson().toJson(appsList, listType);
```

Then an `Exception` is thrown, here is the logcat output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator declares multiple JSON fields named mHandler
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1.create(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:48)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveType
```

I looked up for it in google for hours but not of the answers i found helped me, i am not doing anything special in my code, just copied the lines from the official documentation and replaced it with my object.

Comment: Please post a sample JSON structure that you are having there. This will help figuring out if you have constructed the `MyData` class correctly.

Comment: And moreover, I am not seeing that you are putting something in your `appsList` variable which needs to be converted into a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gson` treats `Drawable` like a regular `POJO` class and iterates over all `getters` and tries to serialise them. It looks like `Drawable` creates cycle with some other objects. Instead of storing whole object, try to serialise only required fields by copying them in constructor:

```
public MyData(String id, String title, Drawable appIcon) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.minWidth = appIcon.getMinimumWidth();
    this.direction = appIcon.getLayoutDirection();
    // copy other fields
}
```

or write custom serialiser for `Drawable` class:

- [Gson Advanced — Custom Serialization for Simplification (Part 1)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-serialization-part-1)
- [GSON - Custom serializer in specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case)

Comment: this was the problem, Thanks!

Comment: @prantibitle, I'm glad to hear that. Also, please, take a look on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)