# How does Gson.fromJson(String, Class) work?

Tags: java, json, gson

Consider following sample Json string :

```
{"Name":"val","FatherName":"val","MotherName":"val"}
```

I convert the above Json to the following pojo :

```
public class Info{
    private String name;
    private String father;
    private String mother;
}
```

What I am wondering is, when I do the following :

```
Gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Info.class);
```

How are the keys in json object tracked to the variables in my pojo ? How is the value of the key `FatherName` stored in `father` in `Info.class`?

Comment: I doubt this json + pojo work together. Just checked: If you add a `toString` to `Info` the output will be "Info{name=null, father=null, mother=null}" which is as expected because Gson (as expected) cannot map anything here.

Comment: [Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is using the reflection(https://android.jlelse.eu/reflections-on-reflection-performance-impact-for-a-json-parser-on-android-d36318c0697c). So the example json will not work as expected in your example there are a couple of option to solve this

1. Change json string to {"name":"val","father":"val","mother":"val"}
2. Change the properties in the info class father-fatherName and the same for mother
   3  Create a custom serializer [GSON - Custom serializer in specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case)

Thanks to @Aaron

you can also annotated the variables with @SerializedName

@SerializedName("father")
private string FatherName;

Comment: Unless I'm missing something using a custom serializer would be overkill and [@SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) should be prefered

Comment: So my example would work only if the keys and member variables of POJO have the same name. But to make my example work, how can I map the keys in json string to the member variables of the pojo ?

Comment: Aaron it should be possible to do this with the @SerializedName  annotation

Comment: Thanks, I tried to explore but just didn't come across `@SerializedName` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, having this class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class UsuariosDTO (
@SerializedName("data") var data: List<Usuarios>
    )
data class Usuarios(
@SerializedName("uid") var uid: String,
@SerializedName("name") var name: String,
@SerializedName("email") var email: String,
@SerializedName("profile_pic") var profilePic: String,
@SerializedName("post") var post: Post
)
data class Post(
@SerializedName("id") var id: Int,
@SerializedName("date") var date: String,
@SerializedName("pics") var pics: List<String>
)
```

I'm able to use (where dataObteined is of UsuariosDTO type):

```
val json = gson.toJson(dataObtained)
```

And later deserialize the json like this:

```
val offUsuariosDTO = gson.fromJson(json, UsuariosDTO::class.java)
```

After looking everywhere I found out my error was UsuariosDTO.class. Since Gson is a java library you have to use UsuariosDTO::class.java