# How to enable/disable one field serialization dynamically in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have one class say Person. When I use gson to convert it into json, sometimes I'd like to include the field `name`, but sometimes I don't want to include it. Is there any api in gson that I can use for this kind of purpose ?

```
class Person {
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

Comment: [GSON - Custom serializer in specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `ExclusionStrategy` in `Gson`. It allows us to define a strategy to tell `GsonBuilder` whether to serialize classes or fields with customized criteria.

**Code snippet**
I use a variable `isNameIgnored` to enable/disable the field `name` to be serialized dynamically.

```
boolean isNameIgnored = false;
ExclusionStrategy strategy = new ExclusionStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
        return isNameIgnored ? "name".equals(field.getName()) : false;
    }
};
```

Then you can apply the strategy to `GsonBuilder` for serialization as follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(strategy)
        .create();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483947/6413377) is correct and the most flexible way to do it.

However depending on the case sometimes you can have benefit of annotation `@Version` if it actually is a question about versioning different cases. So what you can do is make versions of your class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class User {
    @Since(1.0)
    private int id;
    @Since(1.1)
    private String name;
}
```

Then use `GsonBuilder` to decide what version to handle, like:

```
Gson gson10 = getGsonBuilder().setVersion(1.0).create();
Gson gson11 = getGsonBuilder().setVersion(1.1).create();
```

Also

Answer (score 0):

look the [api of gson](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html),we can use the method '`toJson(java.lang.Object src,                   java.lang.Appendable writer)`' to  specific genericized type of `src`. 
so, can we use diffrent type to `enable/disable` the field?