# HashMap to POJO using GSON or Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

My code for conversion:

```
public MyEntity convert(){
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name","akshay");
            map.put("mobile","xxxxxxx");
            map.put("soap","lux");
            map.put("noodles","maggi");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(map);
            MyEntity pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, MyEntity.class);
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(pojo));
            return pojo;
       }
```

My Entity class:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private String name;
    private int mobile;
    private HashMap<String,String> utility;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(int mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUtility() {
        return utility;
    }

    public void setUtility(HashMap<String, String> utility) {
        this.utility = utility;
    }
}
```

What I am getting using my code:

```
{
    "name" : "akshay",
    "mobile" : 1234567890
}
```

But I want output like:

```
{
    "name" : "akshay",
    "mobile" : 1234567890,
    "utility" : {
        "soap" : "lux",
        "noodles" : "maggi"
    }
}
```

GSON does not map SOAP and noodles because there is no corresponding matching object in POJO. That's why I took hashmap. I want GSON to put all the unmatching fields into a hashmap.

One noticeable thing the key-value pair under utility is not fixed depends upon customer purchase. I mean it might be something else like below.

```
{
    "name" : "akshay",
    "mobile" : 1234567890,
    "utility" : {
        "toothpaste" : "colgate",
        "noodles" : "maggi"
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, member variables should be `private`.

Comment: yes thanks, I will edit code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", "akshay");
    map.put("mobile", "xxxxxxx");
    HashMap<String, String> utility = new HashMap<>();
    utility.put("soap", "lux");
    utility.put("noodles", "maggi");
    map.put("utility", utility);
```

GSON ignores soap and noodles since they are not on the right level. They need to be children of "utility".

If you would like a "flat" JSON structure to be parsed in a specific way as you describe (matching fields are mapped 1:1, unmatched fields go into utility), you can write a custom (de)serializer. See this question for an example: [GSON - Custom serializer in specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case). However, I would not recommend this as it probably ends up being more work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to create another map called utility and put inside the first map. Is there any other way then this if yes please help. @aeberhart

Comment: @Monikaverma - This answer gives you the right guidance. And, I do not understand why you do not want to use another `Map`. Looking at your expected output, this is what fits best.

Comment: I tried to explain the reason in the question itself please check @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: @Monikaverma - In fact, your update has made it more obvious why this answer is to-the-point. From your update, however, it's still not clear why you do not want to use another `Map`.

Comment: the reason is very simple I just took name and mobile to make things simple for the question there are hundreds of fields in the map some matching to POJO fields some nonmatching to POJO fields. nonmatching fields should go into the utility section. so segregation problems into two maps. @ArvindKumarAvinash