# How to serialize an inner class as a single value with GSON

Tags: kotlin, serialization, gson

Assume the following two clases

```
class Person internal constructor(var name: String, var address: Address)
```

```
class Address internal constructor(var city: String, var postcode: String)
```

The JSON serialization of this is
`{"name":"Bob","address":{"city":"London","postcode":"LO12 345"}}`

On the API output, I want to serialise the address as a single string, and not an object. e.g. `{"name":"Bob","address":"London, LO12 345"}`

I can achieve this if I write a custom serializer for `Person`, and even managed to work around the issue of only changing this single attribute instead of everything. However, I still have the issue that I now need to change how every single class that uses `Address`.

I am wondering if instead, there is a way to writte a serializer for `Address` that would only return a value instead of an object, much like a primive does. Then I am hoping that every single class that uses `Address`, would behave as if `Address` was a `String` straight away and serialize it as such.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: You can write a custom serialiser for `Address` in the same way that you wrote one for `Person`. What problems did you encounter when doing this? Did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a serialiser for `Address` like this:

```
class AddressSerialiser: JsonSerializer<Address> {
    override fun serialize(p0: Address, p1: Type?, p2: JsonSerializationContext?) =
        JsonPrimitive("${p0.city}, ${p0.postcode}")

}
```

This serialiser outputs a `JsonPrimitive`, which is a string containing the city and postcode.

You can then register this when creating a `Gson`:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Address::class.java, AddressSerialiser())
    .create()
println(gson.toJson(Person("John", Address("Cambridge", "CB5 8HX"))))
```

Output:

```
{"name":"John","address":"Cambridge, CB5 8HX"}
```

Comment: Yes. Yes yes yes yes yes! I must be really bad at internet search because I was looking for a couple of hours! I guess writting down a concise question helps to formulate one's thinking though, because the word "primitive" only ever occured to me when I was writting the stack question! In any case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for but what if you simply make it a data class? Like

```
data class Address internal constructor(var city: String, var postcode: String)
```

Then the `toString()` of it is a very descriptive string, and similar objects also count as equal, like

```
val a = Address("London", "LO12 345")
val b = Address("London", "LO12 345")

println(a) //prints: Address(city=London, postcode=LO12 345)
println(a == b) //prints: true
```